# Apps Script sheet.getCharts() throws Service Error: Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to access the charts on a spreadsheet, with this

```
  var imageSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProperties.getProperty('SHEET_ID')).getSheetByName(scriptProperties.getProperty('CHART_SHEET'));
  var charts = imageSheet.getCharts();
```

When I try this, I get a notification that says

> Service Error: Spreadsheets

I verified that it's definitely opening the correct sheet. This works on a copy of this sheet in my companies G Suitde domain. Could this be related?

Comment: I assume it's `ScriptProperties` and not `scriptProperties` in your code, otherwise you would get a different error. Just to doublecheck: You can correctly retrieve imageSheet and perform any operation on it other than than `getCharts()`? What do you mean by `This works on a copy of this sheet in my companies G Suitde domain`? You mean, you have two different accounts (one GSuite Domain, one free) and if you replace in your script the ID of the sheet on your free account drive with the one on your GSuite domain drive - the same code works? Do you sign out of one account when using the other?

Comment: @ziganotschka

>You can correctly retrieve imageSheet and perform any operation on it other than than getCharts()?

Yes, I can access values inside of the cells of this sheet with `imageSheet.getDataRange().getValues();`.

A coworker of mine created the copy inside of my companies G Suite domain. So the creator of the sheet was a person inside of our G Suite domain. The sheet where the script isn't working was created by the customer. So the creator is outside of our G Suite domain. I suspected it has something to do with that, because I don't have any other clues.

Comment: Are both copies of spreadsheets, charts and scripts now owned by you (the person who runs the script)? And is the content of the sheets (especially the charts) exactly the same?

Comment: It's fixed now. They appeared to be the same, but the charts were actually "empty", even thought they appeared to be filled with data, because they were copy & pasted.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the charts were actually "empty" even though they appeared to be filled with data. This happens if you copy & paste charts from one sheet to another.